# Where replica are stored in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I do not understand this subject, where replica are stored in elasticsearch?

Is primary shard a replica?

So, how ElasticSearch can use replica when the server crashes?

Comment: Like @bsarkar said, one node means no replica shards. Notice that the cluster state is yellow. If you check the health of your cluster you'll find unassigned shards, meaning in this case the replica shards. Solution is to add more nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Elasticsearch index is made up of 1 or more primary shards. Each of these primary shards can have 0 or more replica shards. A replica shard as the name suggests is an exact copy of the corresponding primary shard. Primary and its replica shard(s) are distributed among the cluster nodes such that they do not reside on the same node. This way, if a node containing a primary shard crashes, one of its replica shard that is hosted on another node is promoted to be act as a primary shard. Note: If you have a single node cluster, replica shards will not be allocated as then both primary and replica shards have to reside on the same node which does not make any sense.

There is a lot of material online about this topic. For starters, read [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html) and [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_how_primary_and_replica_shards_interact.html).

Comment: I know them. However, replicas can not be observed. For example, we have a single node and 5(default count) shard with 1(default count) replica. Where in this case the replica?

Comment: On a single node, replica shards are created but not allocated because there is no point having the primary and the replica shards allocated on the same node. If you add more nodes, replica shards will be allocated to a node not containing the primary shard. Executing `GET _cat/shards?v` will reveal that replica shards are created but not allocated on a single node.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. My last question: "On a single node, replica shards are created but not allocated" So they are allocated in memory?

Comment: It's not like a replica shard will be created in memory with all the documents as in the primary shard. They're not allocated at all.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing [the Marvel plugin](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/marvel/current/_installation.html). It has a dashboard where you can see where each shard is located and what its status is.
See below an example.
[image]